# Who owns object returned by QQmlIncubator?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

In the following C++ code, a QML component is created using a `QQmlIncubator`. The Qt documentation has this snippet from here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlincubator.html:

```
QQmlIncubator incubator;
component->create(incubator);

while (!incubator.isReady()) {
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 50);
}

// Who owns 'object'? When is it deleted?
QObject *object = incubator.object();
```

It's my understanding that this snippet isn't totally complete, because you'd need to call `delete` on component. According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcomponent.html#create, the `QQmlComponent::create()` function transfers ownership of the returned object instance to the caller. Good so far.

Now comes my question--who owns `object` in the snippet above? In my case, I've place the above snippet in a member function of a class, so the `QQmlIncubator incubator` goes out of scope, and I only hold on to `component` and `object`, which are both instance variables of their containing class, and I call `delete component` in the destructor. Am I cleaning up properly?

So does `object` belong to `component`? When does `object` get destroyed?

### Update 1

See my follow-up question: [Safely deleting QML component being used in StackView transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864080/safely-deleting-qml-component-being-used-in-stackview-transition).

Comment: At a very quick glance through the code, it looks like the root context. But better not leave object lifetime management to chance https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50319

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

You should destruct the incubated object (if the incubator finished successfully), otherwise a memory leakage occur.

**How to manage ownership?**

A good approach may be to transfer the ownership to an [*object* parent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#parent-prop) using [`QObject::setParent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setParent), for example to the [*visual* parent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#parent-prop). This is also [done by Qt when you construct QML objects in the traditional way](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-visualparent.html):

> Any object assigned to an item's [data](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#data-prop) property becomes a child of the
>   item within its QObject hierarchy, for memory management purposes.
>
> For convenience, the Item [data](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#data-prop) property is its [default property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties).

**Reasoning**

As mentioned in the [`QQmlComponent::create(QQmlContext *)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcomponent.html#create) documentation, the object ownership is transfered to the user:

> The ownership of the returned object instance is transferred to the caller.

So, it is unlikely that the overloaded function [`QQmlComponent::create(QQmlIncubator &incubator, QQmlContext *context, QQmlContext *forContext)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcomponent.html#create-1) will keep the ownership, although it is not mentioned explicitly in the documentation. One could argue that the ownership is transferred to the [`QQmlIncubator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlincubator.html) object. This is indeed the case as long as the component is `Loading`, once it is ready the ownership is released as (implicitly) documented in [`QQmlIncubator::clear`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlincubator.html#clear):

> Any in-progress incubation is aborted. If the incubator is in the Ready state, the created object is **not** deleted.

Note that `QQmlIncubator::clear` is called inside the destructor of `QQmlIncubator`.

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense. I needed to post a follow-up question because my situation is a bit more complicated, but this explains my original question well. Follow up question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864080/safely-deleting-qml-component-being-used-in-stackview-transition

Comment: According to the documentation, the visual parent is set by QQmlQuickItem::setParentItem: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#parent-prop. I think your comment about "transfer the ownership to the visual parent using `QObject::setParent`" might need to be edited. It is my understanding that `QObject::setParent` does not set the visual parent of a QML item.

Comment: @MatthewKraus You are completely right. Is my updated version better?

Comment: thanks for the update. In general I think this approach is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

As currently written in your example, `object` destruction is currently your responsibility. Most likely you will want to take care of that by calling `setParent()` on `object` and thus passing on the responsibility to the parent item.

As you point out about `component->create()`:

> The ownership of the returned object instance is transferred to the
>   caller.

and the incubator gives all appearance of preserving that intention.

An experimental way to verify this would be to check the parent of `object` as returned from the incubator.

Another way to verify this is to look directly at the relevant source code in Qt.  Here are the files for `QQmlIncubator`:

https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/dev/src/qml/qml/qqmlincubator.cpp https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/dev/src/qml/qml/qqmlincubator_p.h
https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/dev/src/qml/qml/qqmlincubator.h

Examining those files, the only place that result is deleted is in the `::clear` method:

```
if (s == Loading) {
    Q_ASSERT(d->compilationUnit);
    if (d->result) d->result->deleteLater();
    d->result = 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not completely agree on your experimental method to check the parent of `object`. The child-parent relationship is only one (common) way to manage the ownership in Qt. As pointed out in your code snippet, clear _does_ take the ownership of the object as long as it is `Loading`, but it is _not_ its parent.

Comment: Ok, so I need to delete the object. But what if QML is still using it? Would you mind looking at my follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864080/safely-deleting-qml-component-being-used-in-stackview-transition

Comment: [`QQuickItem::setParentItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#parent-prop) will not transfer the ownership to the _visual_ parent item. You should use [`QObject::setParent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setParent) instead. See [Concepts - Visual Parent in Qt Quick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-visualparent.html) for more information.